# Logging from Prcess A to Process B

Tags: python, logging, python-multiprocessing

I have twp PyQt Applications.
By clicking a Pushbutton in App A a new Process is created to start App B.

I now want to track the stdout, error and info of App B in a textfield of App A.

I tried using the logging libary but I cant get it to work. I can only ever log the output of App A in the textfield.

I am using Python2, because I cant upgrade atm

This is how App a starts App B

```
# App A
def call_func():
    arg = [python toolB.py]
    p = subprocess.Popen(arg) # i tried to pipe use PIPE.stdout and error , but that doesnt wor either
  
def start_app():
    p = mp.Process(target=call_func)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

App B

- has a logger defined
- is an own PyQt Gui Applcation

Answer (score 0):

the buildin logging module cannot be used in multiprocess environents.

use loguru instead.

https://github.com/Delgan/loguru